# Composite datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow, powerbuilder.net

I have a composite datawindow, running great on PowerBuilder Classic 12.5.
I moved to .net and it is no more working: it displays nothing, either in the application or in the IDE (with preview/retrieve)
The problem does not always happen: with some retrieval arguments, everything works as expected.
The composite datawindow is made by several reports, all same width. The big dw takes some retrieval arguments, then it passes it back to all the component dw (not all component get all the arguments).
By experimenting, I found out that the problem is related to one of the reports, that is a small N-up datawindow, with the data in 3 columns. When I preview/retrieve the N-up dw individually in the IDE, everything works. When I retrieve the composite datawindow:

- When the small N-up dw retrieves more than 3 records, and therefore uses more than one row, everything works
- When the small N-up dw retrieves 3 records or less, the composite dw does not show anything

By looking at the list of changes from Classic to .net I could not find anything helpful.
Can anyone please help?